# Laurus Nobilis parasite identification

Tags: species-identification, parasitology

In north Italy were I live I have two plants of laurus at the two sides of a garden. One of them has some sort of parasite on its leaves.
[image]
Someone know something about it? Leaves are covered with something like an oil.

Comment: Looks like some sort of scale insect. You should add where you're located, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As @picapica has pointed out, I presume these are scale insects, the first instar of Japanese wax scale, *[Ceroplastes japonicus](http://idtools.org/id/scales/factsheet.php?name=6877)*.

Laurus sp. is a host of this hemiptera in Italy.

Here is an image showing the [second instar](https://www.invasive.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5137069) from Italy:
[image]

These are the adult [females](https://www.invasive.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5137065) :

[image]